# React MUI: Autocomplete being used as Popover - Popper component misplaced

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to implement control that includes `TextInput` element that opens a `Popover` when clicked which embeds an `Autocomplete`. When I click on `TextInput`, I am trying to give focus to the list of suggestions (`Popper` element of `Autocomplete`).

**Why do I need it**
That's the way it is (or at least that's what our client wants)

**What is my code**
A simplified version of my code is here

```
import "./styles.css";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";

import { createRef, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";

export default function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const textFieldRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setAnchorEl(textFieldRef.current);
  }, [textFieldRef]);

  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }, []);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <>
      <TextField id='textfield' ref={textFieldRef} onClick={handleClick} fullWidth />
      <Popover
        id='popover'
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        disablePortal
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 54,
          horizontal: 0
        }}
      >
        <Autocomplete
          id='autocomplete'

          openOnFocus
          options={["abc"]}
          freeSolo
          multiple
          fullWidth
          value={[""]}
          PopperComponent={(props) => <Popper {...props} anchorEl={anchorEl}/>}
          renderOption={(props, option) => (
            <Box component="li" {...props}>
              {option}
            </Box>
          )}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              autoFocus
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Popover>
    </>
  );
}
```

**What is the problem**
The `Poppover` is misplaced on focus as shown below

[image]

When I click on `Autocomplete` (or generally re-render the screen), it corrects itself

[image]

**Why does it happen**
(My guess is) that there is a delay in rendering `Autocomplete` and the `Popper` does not have an anchor when it is rendered first time. I can see the delay by putting a conditional statement (e.g.

```
{ document.getElementById('popover`) && <Autocomplete ...
```

**What is my solution**
I tried many things (I mean **many**). The best I can do is to use

```
<Autocomplete...
PopperComponent={(props) => <Popper {...props}
              anchorEl={document.getElementById('textfield')
    modifiers={[
                {
                  name: 'offset',
                  options: { offset: [32.5, 58], },
                },
              ]}/>...
```

There are two problems - one - it is super ugly, two - the `Autocomplete` box grows if I add more entries and I need to somehow adjust the offset accordingly (much more ugly)

*Any suggestions are greatly appreciated~*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same issue. I raised it with MUI support and here is the solution they offered:

> When the Popover appears, for a brief moment, it isn't correctly positioned yet. Because of this, the Autocomplete listbox also shows itself in an incorrect position. The workaround here could be to wait until the popover appeared before opening the autocomplete. You can use Popover's TransitionProps.onEntered for this.

Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-andras-pfkcn4?file=/src/App.tsx):

```
import "./styles.css";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";

import { createRef, useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";

export default function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const textFieldRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  const autocompleteTextFieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setAnchorEl(textFieldRef.current);
  }, [textFieldRef]);

  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }, []);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <>
      <TextField ref={textFieldRef} onClick={handleClick} fullWidth />
      <Popover
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        disablePortal
        TransitionProps={{
          onEntered: () => autocompleteTextFieldRef.current.focus()
        }}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 54,
          horizontal: 0
        }}
      >
        <Autocomplete
          openOnFocus
          options={["abc"]}
          freeSolo
          multiple
          fullWidth
          value={[""]}
          renderOption={(props, option) => (
            <Box component="li" {...props}>
              {option}
            </Box>
          )}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} inputRef={autocompleteTextFieldRef} />
          )}
        />
      </Popover>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that getElementById is async / appears as sync, don't use it as an arg, use it in a useEffect with empty arg and set its value in the component.